# MSSQL. Создание группы с определенными правами

Tags: sql-server, права, доступ

Необходимо дать права только на выполнение данной команды:

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'MSDASQL',
    'Driver={Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)};DBQ=shara',
    'SELECT * FROM table2');
```

Т.е. что бы члены группы имели доступ только table, могли выполнять команду `OPENROWSET` - не больше и не меньше.

Не подскажете как дать права правильно или где почитать?

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы.

Comment: Сделайте хранимую процедуру, выполняющую данный запрос, и дайте права исключительно на выполнение этой процедуры.

Comment: @Yaant - это не сработает, если есть смена схемы. Если везде схема dbo - то без вопросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может быть вам подойдёт такой вариант. Заворачиваем команду в хранимую процедуру:

```
create procedure [dbo].[ImportProc]
with execute as 'UserName' -- тот у кого есть права на table и OPENROWSET
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO [table]
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET(...);
end
```

далее создать роль, дать ей права на выполнение процедуры и добавить нужных пользователей в роль:

```
USE [DBName]
GO
CREATE ROLE [data_import]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[ImportProc] TO [data_import]
GO
ALTER ROLE [data_import] ADD MEMBER [DataImporterUserName]
GO
```

Если нет, то для использования `OPENROWSET` нужно давать разрешение уровня сервера `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` соответствующему логину:

```
USE [master]
GO
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [LoginName]
GO
```

Плюс в базе нужно отдельно разрешить вставку в таблицу:

```
USE [DBName]
GO
GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[table] TO [RoleName]
GO
```